# Is there a way to access elements inside shadow-root (Closed)

Tags: css, shadow, shadow-dom

Is there anyway to access the element inside the shadow-root (Closed)

Comment: The only way would be to overload the attachShadow function before it is called and to replace the closed mode be the open mode

Comment: Thank you, can you please help me on how to use the method attachShadow in my python script.